# Material-UI's Tabs integration with react router 4?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-router-v4

The new react-router syntax uses the `Link` component to move around the routes. But how could this be integrated with `material-ui`?

In my case, I'm using tabs as the main navigation system, So in theory I should have something like this:

```js
const TabLink = ({ onClick, href, isActive, label }) => 
  <Tab
    label={label}
    onActive={onClick}
  />



export default class NavBar extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <Tabs>
        <Link to="/">{params => <TabLink label="Home" {...params}/>}</Link>
        <Link to="/shop">{params => <TabLink label="shop" {...params}/>}</Link>
        <Link to="/gallery">{params => <TabLink label="gallery" {...params}/>}</Link>
      </Tabs>
    )
  }
}
```

But when it renders, material-ui throws an error that the child of `Tabs` must be a `Tab` component. What could be the way to proceed? How do I manage the `isActive` prop for the tab?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Answered in full here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/47396910/4180797

Answer (score 36, accepted):

My instructor helped me with using React Router 4.0's withRouter to wrap the Tabs component to enable history methods like so:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {Tabs, Tab} from 'material-ui';
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

import Home from "./Home";
import Portfolio from "./Portfolio";

class NavTabs extends Component {

 handleCallToRouter = (value) => {
   this.props.history.push(value);
 }

  render () {
     return (
      <Tabs
        value={this.props.history.location.pathname}
        onChange={this.handleCallToRouter}
        >
        <Tab
          label="Home"
          value="/"
        >
        <div>
           <Home />
        </div>
        </Tab>
        <Tab
          label="Portfolio"
          value="/portfolio"
            >
          <div>
            <Portfolio />
          </div>
        </Tab>
      </Tabs>           
    )
  }
}

export default withRouter(NavTabs)
```

Simply add BrowserRouter to index.js and you're good to go.

Comment: This is good but due to `value={this.props.history.location.pathname}` it will cause the error: ``Warning: Material-UI: the value provided `/portfolio/123` is invalid`` if you add routing to a specific element or any route that is not defined in tabs.

Comment: I could not get my tabs highlighted with this

Answer (score 121):

Another solution (https://codesandbox.io/s/l4yo482pll) with no handlers nor HOCs, just pure react-router and material-ui components:

```html
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Tabs from "@material-ui/core/Tabs";
import Tab from "@material-ui/core/Tab";
import { Switch, Route, Link, BrowserRouter, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  const allTabs = ['/', '/tab2', '/tab3'];

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="App">
        <Route
          path="/"
          render={({ location }) => (
            <Fragment>
              <Tabs value={location.pathname}>
                <Tab label="Item One" value="/" component={Link} to={allTabs[0]} />
                <Tab label="Item Two" value="/tab2" component={Link} to={allTabs[1]} />
                <Tab
                  value="/tab3"
                  label="Item Three"
                  component={Link}
                  to={allTabs[2]}
                />
              </Tabs>
              <Switch>
                <Route path={allTabs[1]} render={() => <div>Tab 2</div>} />
                <Route path={allTabs[2]} render={() => <div>Tab 3</div>} />
                <Route path={allTabs[0]} render={() => <div>Tab 1</div>} />
              </Switch>
            </Fragment>
          )}
        />
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: code sandbox is deead ModuleNotFoundError: Could not find module in path: '@babel/runtime/helpers/builtin/interopRequireDefault' relative to '/node_modules/@material-ui/core/Tabs/index.js'

Comment: this `codesandbox` is no more working, please edit it

Comment: Instead of making `allTabs` an array I recommend object like `const allTabs = {home: '/', tab2: '/tab2', tab3: '/tab3'}` it's much easier this way than scrolling back and forth to figure out which index is which tab.

Answer (score 6):

The error you are seeing from material-ui is because it expects to have a `<Tab>` component rendered as direct child of `<Tabs>` component.

Now, here is a way that I've found to integrate the link into the `<Tabs>` component without loosing the styles:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Tabs, Tab} from 'material-ui/Tabs';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

export default class MyComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        const {location} = this.props;
        const {pathname} = location;

        return (
            <Tabs value={pathname}>
                <Tab label="First tab" containerElement={<Link to="/my-firs-tab-view" />} value="/my-firs-tab-view">
                    {/* insert your component to be rendered inside the tab here */}
                </Tab>
                <Tab label="Second tab" containerElement={<Link to="/my-second-tab-view" />} value="/my-second-tab-view">
                    {/* insert your component to be rendered inside the tab here */}
                </Tab>
            </Tabs>
        );
    }
}
```

To manage the 'active' property for the tabs, you can use the `value` property in the `<Tabs>` component and you also need to have a `value` property for each tab, so when both of the properties match, it will apply the active style to that tab.

Comment: where is `containerElement` in the doc?  How is it being used?

Answer (score 3):

Solution with Tab highlight, Typescript based and works well with react-route v5:

Explanation: `<Tab/>` here work as a link to React router. Values in `<Tab/> to={'/all-event'}` and `value={'/all-event'}` should be same in order to highlgiht

```
import { Container, makeStyles, Tab, Tabs } from '@material-ui/core';
import React from 'react';
import {
  Link,
  Route,
  Switch,
  useLocation,
  Redirect,
} from 'react-router-dom';
import AllEvents from './components/AllEvents';
import UserEventsDataTable from './components/UserEventsDataTable';

const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  container: {
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
}));

function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const location = useLocation();

  return (
    <>
      <Container className={classes.container}>
        <Tabs value={location.pathname}>
          <Tab
            label='All Event'
            component={Link}
            to={`/all-event`}
            value={`/all-event`}
          />
          <Tab
            label='User Event'
            component={Link}
            to={`/user-event`}
            value={`/user-event`}
          />
        </Tabs>

      </Container>
      <Switch>
        <Route path={`/all-event`}>
          <AllEvents />
        </Route>
        <Route path={`/user-event`}>
          <UserEventsDataTable />
        </Route>
        <Route path={`/`}>
          <Redirect from='/' to='/all-event' />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another solution, using the beta of Material 1.0 and adding browser Back/Forward to the mix:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';
import Tabs, { Tab } from 'material-ui/Tabs';
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Home";
import Portfolio from "./Portfolio";

function TabContainer(props) {
  return <div style={{ padding: 20 }}>{props.children}</div>;
}

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    width: '100%',
    marginTop: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
  },
});

class NavTabs extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: "/",
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    window.onpopstate = ()=> {
      this.setState({
        value: this.props.history.location.pathname
      });
  }
}

  handleChange = (event, value) => {
    this.setState({ value });
    this.props.history.push(value);
  };

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const { value } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <AppBar position="static" color="default">
          <Tabs
            value={value}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            scrollable
            scrollButtons="on"
            indicatorColor="primary"
            textColor="primary"
          >
            <Tab label="Home" value = "/" />
            <Tab label="Portfolio" value = "/portfolio"/>
          </Tabs>
        </AppBar>
        {value === "/" && <TabContainer>{<Home />}</TabContainer>}
        {value === "/portfolio" && <TabContainer>{<Portfolio />}</TabContainer>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

NavTabs.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withRouter(withStyles(styles)(NavTabs));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `browserHistory` instead of React-Router `Link` component

```
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'

// Go to /some/path.
onClick(label) {
  browserHistory.push('/${label}');
}

// Example for Go back
//browserHistory.goBack()

<Tabs>
  <Tab
    label={label}
    onActive={() => onClick(label)}
  />
</Tabs>
```

As you see you can simply `push()` your target to the `browserHistory`

Comment: In v4 there isn't any `browserHistory`, look at their [index.js](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v4/packages/react-router-dom/modules/index.js).

Comment: There is something similar in passed props `props.push(url, state)`

Answer (score 1):

As @gkatchmar says you can use `withRouter` high-order component but you can also use `context API`. Since @gkatchmar showed withRouter already I will only show `context API`. Bear in mind that this is an experimental API.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42716055/3850405

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {Tabs, Tab} from 'material-ui';
import * as PropTypes from "prop-types";

export class NavTabs extends Component {
constructor(props) {
 super(props);
}

static contextTypes = {
    router: PropTypes.object
}

handleChange = (event: any , value: any) => {
    this.context.router.history.push(value);
};

  render () {
     return (
      <Tabs
        value={this.context.router.history.location.pathname}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        >
        <Tab
          label="Home"
          value="/"
        >
        <div>
           <Home />
        </div>
        </Tab>
        <Tab
          label="Portfolio"
          value="/portfolio"
            >
          <div>
            <Portfolio />
          </div>
        </Tab>
      </Tabs>           
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution using the `useLocation` hook. No state needed. React router v5 though.

```js
import { Tab, Tabs } from '@material-ui/core';
import { matchPath, NavLink, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const navItems = [
  {
    id: 'one',
    path: '/one',
    text: 'One',
  },
  {
    id: 'two',
    path: '/two',
    text: 'Two',
  },
  {
    id: 'three',
    path: '/three',
    text: 'Three',
  },
];

export default function Navigation() {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();
  const activeItem = navItems.find((item) => !!matchPath(pathname, { path: item.path }));
  return (
    <Tabs value={activeItem?.id}>
      {navItems.map((item) => (
        <Tab key={item.id} value={item.id} label={item.text} component={NavLink} to={item.path} />
      ))}
    </Tabs>
  );
}
```

Comment: i had no clue they offered matchPath, thank you ily sm ❤️

Answer (score 0):

```
 <BrowserRouter>
<div className={classes.root}>
  <AppBar position="static" color="default">
    <Tabs
      value={this.state.value}
      onChange={this.handleChange}
      indicatorColor="primary"
      textColor="primary"
      fullWidth
    >
      <Tab label="Item One" component={Link} to="/one" />
      <Tab label="Item Two" component={Link} to="/two" />
    </Tabs>
  </AppBar>

  <Switch>
    <Route path="/one" component={PageShell(ItemOne)} />
    <Route path="/two" component={PageShell(ItemTwo)} />
  </Switch>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you add a few words to explain your code and how it answers the OP's question?

Answer (score 0):

I've created this hook to help control the tabs and generate the default value that catches from the location URL.

```
const useTabValue = (array, mainPath = "/") => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const { pathname } = useLocation();
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
  const pathArray = pathname.split("/");

  function handleChange(_, nextEvent) {
    setValue(nextEvent);
    history.push(`${mainPath}/${array[nextEvent]}`);
  }

  const findDefaultValue = useCallback(() => {
    return array.forEach((el) => {
      if (pathArray.indexOf(el) > 0) {
        setValue(array.indexOf(el));
        return;
      }
    });
  }, [pathArray, array]);

  useEffect(() => {
    findDefaultValue();
  }, [findDefaultValue]);
  return {
    handleChange,
    value,
  };
};
```

then I have used it like this :

```
const NavigationBar = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const allTabs = useMemo(() => ["home", "search"]);
  const { handleChange, value } = useTabValue(allTabs, "/dashboard");
  return (
    <div className={classes.navBarContainer}>
      <Tabs
        centered
        value={value}
        variant="fullWidth"
        onChange={handleChange}
        className={classes.navBar}
      >
        <Tab color="textPrimary" icon={<HomeIcon />} />
        <Tab color="textPrimary" icon={<ExploreIcon />} />
      </Tabs>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this in a much easier fashion (I was surprised this worked so well - maybe there's a problem I haven't found out). I'm using Router 6 and React 17 (I know these packages are newer).
In any case, I just used the useNavigate hook in the handleChange function. Thus, now there is NO need for Switch and the code becomes much simpler. See below:

```
let navigate = useNavigate();
const [selection, setSelection] = useState();

const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setSelection(newValue);
    navigate(`${newValue}`);
}

return (
    <Tabs value={selection} onChange={handleChange}>
         <Tab label="Products" value="products"  />
         <Tab label="Customers" value="customers" />
         <Tab label="Invoices" value="invoices" />
    </Tabs>
  );
}
```

The handleChange function updates 'selection' which controls the display of the tabs, and also navigates to the right path.
if you set the  component somewhere in your React space, and set correctly a :style route (as explained by React Router: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview), you can also control in which area of the page will the content be rendered. Hope it helps somebody!

Answer (score -1):

I got it working this way in my app:

```
import React, {useEffect, useRef} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {makeStyles} from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Tabs from '@material-ui/core/Tabs';
import Tab from '@material-ui/core/Tab';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';
import Container from "@material-ui/core/Container";
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
import MenuIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Menu";
import VideoCallIcon from "@material-ui/icons/VideoCall";

const docStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    root: {
        display: 'flex',
        '& > * + *': {
            marginLeft: theme.spacing(2),
        },
    },
    appBarRoot: {
        flexGrow: 1,
    },
    headline: {
        marginTop: theme.spacing(2),
    },
    bodyCopy: {
        marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
        fontSize: '1.2rem',
    },
    tabContents: {
        margin: theme.spacing(3),
    },
}));

function TabPanel(props) {
    const {children, value, index, classes, ...other} = props;

    return (
        <div
            role="tabpanel"
            hidden={value !== index}
            id={`simple-tabpanel-${index}`}
            aria-labelledby={`simple-tab-${index}`}
            {...other}
        >
            {value === index && (
                <Container>
                    <Box className={classes.tabContents}>
                        {children}
                    </Box>
                </Container>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}

function a11yProps(index) {
    return {
        id: `simple-tab-${index}`,
        'aria-controls': `simple-tabpanel-${index}`,
    };
}

function TabOneContents(props) {
    const {classes} = props;
    return (
        <>
            <Typography variant="h4" component={'h1'} className={classes.headline}>
                Headline 1
            </Typography>

            <Typography variant="body1" className={classes.bodyCopy}>
                Body Copy 1
            </Typography>
        </>
    )
}

function TabTwoContents(props) {
    const {classes} = props;
    const nurseOnboardingPath = '/navigator/onboarding/' + Meteor.userId() + '/1';

    return (
        <>
            <Typography variant="h4" component={'h1'} className={classes.headline}>
                Headline 2
            </Typography>

            <Typography variant="body1" className={classes.bodyCopy}>
                Body Copy 2
            </Typography>
        </>
    )
}

export default function MUITabPlusReactRouterDemo(props) {
    const {history, match} = props;
    const propsForDynamicClasses = {};
    const classes = docStyles(propsForDynamicClasses);
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState(history.location.pathname.includes('/tab_2') ? 1 : 0);

    const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
        setValue(newValue);
        const pathName = '/' + (value == 0 ? 'tab_1' : 'tab_2');
        history.push(pathName);
    };


    return (
        <div className={classes.appBarRoot}>
            <AppBar position="static" color="transparent">
                <Tabs value={value} onChange={handleChange} aria-label="How It Works" textColor="primary">
                    <Tab label="Tab 1" {...a11yProps(0)} />
                    <Tab label="Tab 2" {...a11yProps(1)} />
                </Tabs>
            </AppBar>
            <TabPanel value={value} index={0} classes={classes}>
                <TabOneContents classes={classes}/>
            </TabPanel>
            <TabPanel value={value} index={1} classes={classes}>
                <TabTwoContents classes={classes}/>
            </TabPanel>
        </div>
    );
}
```

...and in React Router:

```
[.....]
<Route exact path="/tab_1"
       render={(routeProps) =>
           <MUITabPlusReactRouterDemo history={routeProps.history}
           />
       }/>

<Route exact path="/tab_2"
       render={(routeProps) =>
           <MUITabPlusReactRouterDemo history={routeProps.history}                           />
       }/>
[.....]
```